# Scalable deployer in SDL Tridion Sites 9 is unstable

Tags: content-delivery, deployer, sites-9

We have setup a scalable deployer in SDL Tridion Sites 9 like in the picture below. With 2 Deployer endpoints, 2 workers, Apache MQ (JMS) and a NetApp CIFS fileshare. We noticed that bulk publishing is unstable. We see a lot of failures. After ivestigatating the logs we can see the following type of errors:

Deployer worker (cd_core.log)

```
2019-09-23 16:22:28,825 ERROR [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18] StepActor - Step 'TridionUnzipStep' for 'tcm:0-5378475-66560' can NOT retry
2019-09-23 16:22:28,825 ERROR [ProcessingAkkaSpringContext-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18] StepActor - Step 'TridionUnzipStep' for 'tcm:0-5378475-66560': 
com.sdl.delivery.deployer.api.processing.exception.ProcessingException: Couldn't unzip. File:tcm_0-5378475-66560.Content.zip
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionUnzipStep.unzipAndMove(TridionUnzipStep.java:288)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionUnzipStep.process(TridionUnzipStep.java:164)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.execute(StepActor.scala:72)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.com$sdl$delivery$deployer$engine$pipeline$actor$StepActor$$processStep(StepActor.scala:57)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(StepActor.scala:40)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.StepActor.aroundReceive(StepActor.scala:26)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:588)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \\naf4394.aad.nl\tridion01$\temp\tridion\live\binary\Binaries\tcm_0-5378475-66560.Content.zip (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

[image: Scalable Deployer]

The error is saying it cannot find the file specified but the file is still present on the file system?

We only see these kind of errors on the Live deployers (1 deployer + 2 workers) and not on the Staging deployer (deployer-combined). The staging deployer is deploying to the local file system and the live deployers to a NetApp share (\naf4394.aad.nl\tridion01$)

[image]

Comment: Please check this link consists of troublehshooting steps
 https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000007426

Comment: Have you considered posting it as an answer @k951?

Comment: @Shiva if it helps the user who has raised question, then will consider it as an answer, ask the user to accept it as answer bu there is no response from Gert de Heul. For me when I was facing issue the link which I have posted in my comments helped me to resolve the issue